# Get IP's in Autonomous System Number (ASN)

Tags: php, networking, dns, ip

I've tried getting the list of IP's under an ASN number for example AS8167 however I am having no such luck. I have seen that team cymru have an IP to ASN, however that is the opposite of what I actually need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RADb has a whois server that provides this functionality. It includes information other than just the IP blocks, so you'll need to grep for those if that's all you're interested in:

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS8167' | grep -Eo "([0-9.]+){4}/[0-9]+" | head
189.11.64.0/18
189.31.0.0/16
189.72.128.0/18
189.73.192.0/18
189.74.0.0/18
189.74.64.0/18
189.64.0.0/11
189.0.0.0/11
187.52.192.0/18
187.52.0.0/17
```

Comment: Excellent approach, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't recommend that regex. It would match `1234/0` if some other field (mnt-by, remarks, etc) happen to contain that pattern by chance. I would use awk to filter route lines: `whois ... | awk '/^route:/{ print $2 }'`. Remove the semi-colon to include ipv6, or change the semi-colon to "6" to get only ipv6.

Answer (score 4):

Hurricane Electric has a service that was made specifically for this and other IP related purposes.

Try this: http://bgp.he.net/AS8167#_prefixes

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IP Guide](https://ip.guide) to look up the IPs announced by an ASN with something like this:

```
curl -sL https://ip.guide/as16509 | jq .routes
```

Which will return something like:

```
{
  "v4": [
    "1.44.96.0/24",
    "2.57.12.0/24",
    ...
  ],
  "v6": [
    "2001:4f8:b::/48",
    "2001:4f8:11::/48",
  ]
}
```

(jq isn't necessary here, but it helps traverse the JSON-based response)

Or if you're looking for a way to do this in PHP:

```
<?php

// Initialize cURL session
$curl = curl_init('https://ip.guide/as16509');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

if (isset($data['v4']) && isset($data['v6'])) {
    echo "IPv4 Routes:\n";
    foreach ($data['v4'] as $route) {
        echo $route . "\n";
    }

    echo "\nIPv6 Routes:\n";
    foreach ($data['v6'] as $route) {
        echo $route . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: Invalid response from API";
}

?>
```